# Print a Specific Field From Last But One Line

Tags: perl, bash, awk

I am trying to parse this output:

```
$ top -b -d 1 -n 1 -p 5997
top - 08:54:39 up 86 days,  2:42,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  8.9%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.5%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3869696k total,  2010912k used,  1858784k free,   162404k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   736120k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5997 tomcat7   20   0 1209m 534m 6940 S  0.0 14.2  14:40.85 java

$
```

my expected output is:

```
534m
```

So I want to get the `6th` field from `second last line`. (the last line is an empty line, hence I am looking at `second last` line)

Here is my solution:

```
$ top -b -d 1 -n 1 -p 5997 | awk 'NF > 0' | awk 'END {print $6}'
539m
```

I first remove the blank lines and then extract the 6th field from the last line. And it works. Perfect !!!

**QUESTION:**

I did not like using **2** `awk` pipes. So there must be an elegant solution to achieve the same using a single `awk` statement. Could you help me with that.

Even a `Perl` oneliner would be helpful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can of course combine top and awk to get any text part you want. but for your requirement, I think `ps` suits you better:

```
ps -h --format rss <PID>
```

this will give you the same number in `Kilobytes`. if you love to have the `m` at end, you can just `/1024`.

**EDIT**

Even if Jonta has reported the version diff problem. I still don't think parsing output of top to  get a memory usage is the best way. this would be the generic solution:

```
grep -oP 'VmRSS:\s*\K.*' /proc/<PID>/status
```

here is my output both with above command and the `ps` one:

```
kent$  ps -h -o rss 25579                             
405304

kent$  grep -oP 'VmRSS:\s*\K\d*' /proc/25579/status 
405304
```

you can easily replace the `grep` with other powerful tool, like bc, awk... to get `mb` unit if you like.

Comment: This gives me: `ps -h --format rss 11715
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
  284`  correct value, but an error message.

Comment: which version do you have? Here works with `procps-ng version 3.3.9`, you can also try: `ps -h -o rss <PID>` or read man page, there should be option to format output. @Jotne

Comment: @Jotne I have the same version as Imaginations. I tried with `-o`, works too.

Comment: @Jotne I added another way to get the data. in case you have different `ps` version.

Comment: @Jotne I am using 'procps-ng version 3.3.3', `ps h -o rss <PID>` works and does not give any warning.

Comment: Yes, `ps h -o rss <PID>` works for me and it is faster as well. Thanks for point this out.

Comment: +1 Nice, attacking the problem instead of the symptoms

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
awk 'now { print $6; exit } $1 == "PID" { now = 1 }'
```

Explanation:

- The commands are evaluated for each line of input
- The variable `now` is unset, so the block of `now { ... }` is not executed by default
- When the first field is "PID", we set `now` to 1, so that when the next line comes, the `now { ... }` block will be executed
- In the `now { ... }` block we print the 6th field and exit to stop processing

Comment: Works. +1. Would you please explain what it is doing. I know very basic of `awk`

Comment: Hi, Although this answer works, I will be selecting @Kent's answer as it also provides right way of pulling the mem usage. I was doing is using `top` which is not a good way. Thanks.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I agree, Kent's answer is better, go for it!

Answer (score 1):

```
top -b -d 1 -n 1 -p 5997 | perl -anE '@r=@F if @F; END{ say $r[5] }'
```

perl loops over lines and stores column values in `@F`. It also stores the same values into `@r` array but only when there are actual values (for non-empty lines). 
At the end outputs column for last non-empty line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would have done it with `awk`

```
awk '/PID/ {getline;print $6}'
```

This will search for line with `PID`, get the next line and print field `$6`

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but general) way to get second-to-last line:

```
$ echo -e "abc\ndef\nijk" | tail -2 | head -1
```

Comment: He did not like 2 pipes

Comment: @Jotne I aware of that, just want to give a general way to extract the second-to-last line.